# Playwright won't launch browser in Docker container

Tags: docker, containers, playwright, playwright-test

I am trying to deploy my playwright automation framework in a docker container. However I assume that the browser won't launch (don't have any logs).

When I run my tests locally in VS code, they look like this:
[image: Playwright Local Execution]

When I run my tests in Docker container, they look like this:
[image: Docker execution]

It is clear that it is missing the [Google Chrome] or [chromium] at the beginning of the line. I assume that the browser is not getting launched.

My dockerfile looks like this:

```
# playwright:bionic has everything to run playwright (node, npm, chromium, dependencies)
#FROM mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:bionic
#COPY .. .
FROM node:14
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:focal
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package*.json /app/
#COPY features/ /app/features/
COPY src/ /app/src/
#COPY cucumber.js /app/
#COPY tsconfig.json /app/
#COPY reports/ /app/reports/
COPY *.config.json /app/
RUN npm install
RUN npx playwright install
CMD npm run test
#ENTRYPOINT ["npm run test"]
```

Any ideas how to get the tests to run in a container?

Answer (score 2):

If not using the mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:bionic with all the dependencies, add this line after the `RUN npx playwright install` to get the browser binaries:

```
COPY  /root/.cache/ms-playwright/ /root/.cache/ms-playwright/
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem was fixed by adding:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:bionic
```

which added all the needed dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can start from the provided image `mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.16.2-focal`:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.16.2-focal
# copy project files
COPY . /e2e

WORKDIR /e2e

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install
RUN npx playwright install

# Run playwright test
CMD [ "npx", "playwright", "test", "--reporter=list" ]
```

The `--reporter=list` option is to print a line for each test being executed.