# Playwright browser launch error in Docker container with AdonisJS project

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, playwright, adonisjs-ace

I'm encountering an issue with my Dockerized AdonisJS project where Playwright is unable to launch the browser, resulting in the error message:

```
M browserType.launch: Executable doesn't exist at /root/.cache/ms-playwright/chromium-1105/chrome-linux/chrome
```

[image: error]

**Here's my Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:20.11.1-alpine as base

# Install dependencies needed by Playwright
RUN apk add --no-cache \
    libxkbcommon \
    dbus \
    ttf-freefont \
    udev \
    xvfb \
    zlib \
    chromium \
    chromium-chromedriver \
    nss \
    freetype \
    freetype-dev \
    harfbuzz \
    ca-certificates \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

# install dependences
FROM base as deps
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
# Install Playwright and browsers
RUN npx playwright install

# Production only deps stage
FROM base as production-deps
WORKDIR /app
ADD package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install 
# Install Playwright and browsers
RUN npx playwright install

# Build
FROM base as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules /app/node_modules
COPY . .
COPY .env.example .env
RUN npm run build

# Set the entry point for the container
FROM base
ENV NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=production-deps /app/node_modules /app/node_modules
COPY --from=build /app/build /app
COPY .env.example .env
EXPOSE 3333
CMD ["node", "./bin/server.js"]
```

The Dockerfile installs all the necessary dependencies for Playwright and my AdonisJS project. However, when I run the container, I receive the mentioned error.

I've verified that npx playwright install is executed during the Docker build process. Additionally, the Dockerfile copies all files, including the modules, into a folder named app.

I'm trying that but doesnt work [Playwright won't launch browser in Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71422902/playwright-wont-launch-browser-in-docker-container)

**Package JSON**

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "license": "UNLICENSED", 
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node bin/server.js",
    "build": "node ace build",
    "dev": "node ace serve --watch",
    "test": "node ace test",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "format": "prettier --write .",
    "typecheck": "tsc --noEmit"
  },
  "imports": {
    "#controllers/*": "./app/controllers/*.js",
    "#exceptions/*": "./app/exceptions/*.js",
    "#models/*": "./app/models/*.js",
    "#mails/*": "./app/mails/*.js",
    "#services/*": "./app/services/*.js",
    "#listeners/*": "./app/listeners/*.js",
    "#events/*": "./app/events/*.js",
    "#middleware/*": "./app/middleware/*.js",
    "#validators/*": "./app/validators/*.js",
    "#providers/*": "./providers/*.js",
    "#policies/*": "./app/policies/*.js",
    "#abilities/*": "./app/abilities/*.js",
    "#database/*": "./database/*.js",
    "#start/*": "./start/*.js",
    "#tests/*": "./tests/*.js",
    "#config/*": "./config/*.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@adonisjs/assembler": "^7.1.1",
    "@adonisjs/eslint-config": "^1.2.1",
    "@adonisjs/prettier-config": "^1.2.1",
    "@adonisjs/tsconfig": "^1.2.1",
    "@japa/api-client": "^2.0.2",
    "@japa/assert": "^2.1.0",
    "@japa/plugin-adonisjs": "^3.0.0",
    "@japa/runner": "^3.1.1",
    "@swc/core": "^1.3.107",
    "@types/hbs": "^4.0.4",
    "@types/jsdom": "^21.1.6",
    "@types/luxon": "^3.4.2",
    "@types/node": "^20.11.25",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.17",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "pino-pretty": "^10.3.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.35",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3",
    "vite": "^5.1.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@adonisjs/auth": "^9.1.1",
    "@adonisjs/core": "^6.2.2",
    "@adonisjs/cors": "^2.2.1",
    "@adonisjs/lucid": "^20.1.0",
    "@adonisjs/session": "^7.1.1",
    "@adonisjs/vite": "^2.0.2",
    "@vinejs/vine": "^1.7.1",
    "better-sqlite3": "^9.4.3",
    "edge.js": "^6.0.1",
    "handlebars": "^4.7.8",
    "hbs": "^4.2.0",
    "jsdom": "^24.0.0",
    "luxon": "^3.4.4",
    "playwright": "^1.42.0",
    "puppeteer": "^22.3.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.2.1"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "@adonisjs/eslint-config/app"
  },
  "prettier": "@adonisjs/prettier-config"
}
```

Is there something I'm missing in my Docker setup or Playwright configuration that could be causing this issue? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have access to all of the details of your project, but here's a minimal setup that works and which you can build on for your setup.

`Dockerfile` (I changed from the Alpine base image to the Debian base image because it works better with Chrome system dependencies. Also copy the Chrome executable across from the `build` stage.)

```
FROM node:20.11.1 as base

RUN apt-get update -q && \
    apt-get install -q -y libasound2 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libgtk-4-1 libnss3 xdg-utils

# =============================================================================

FROM base as deps
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install

# =============================================================================

FROM base as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules /app/node_modules
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# =============================================================================

FROM base
ENV NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules /app/node_modules
COPY --from=deps /root/.cache/ /root/.cache/
COPY --from=build /app/build /app/bin
EXPOSE 3333
CMD ["node", "./bin/server.js"]
```

`package.json` (I used `postinstall` script to install the Chromium executable.)

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node ace serve --watch",
    "build": "node ace build --production",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "test": "node ace test",
    "postinstall": "playwright install chromium"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@adonisjs/assembler": "^5.9.6",
    "@japa/preset-adonis": "^1.2.0",
    "@japa/runner": "^2.5.1",
    "@types/proxy-addr": "^2.0.3",
    "@types/source-map-support": "^0.5.10",
    "adonis-preset-ts": "^2.1.0",
    "pino-pretty": "^11.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.6",
    "youch": "^3.3.3",
    "youch-terminal": "^2.2.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@adonisjs/core": "^5.9.0",
    "playwright": "^1.42.1",
    "proxy-addr": "^2.0.7",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.2.1",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.21"
  }
}
```

`server.ts` (Just loads a page and checks for correct title.)

```
import { chromium } from 'playwright';

async function launchChrome() {
  const browser = await chromium.launch({
    headless: true,
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto('https://example.com');

  const expectedTitle = 'Example Domain';
  const title = await page.title();

  console.log(`Page Title: ${title}`);
  if (title === expectedTitle) {
    console.log('The page was loaded successfully.');
  } else {
    console.error('The page did not load as expected.');
  }

  await browser.close();
}

launchChrome().catch(err => {
  console.error(err);
  process.exit(1);
});
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! The main issue turned out to be related to dependencies and the way I was copying files. Your solution really saved me! I had been struggling with this problem for a while. Now I have a better understanding of how to structure future projects correctly. Thanks again

Comment: Hello @datawookie! Me again, can I ask you a question about this?